# Can a Docker volume do transparent decompression for read-only files?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

*tl;dr* What are best practices for exposing read-only data to a Dockerized app, with transparent decompression?

I have a Dockerized app which needs read-only access to a set of data files totalling 80 GB. Currently, I manually copy these to hosts, and expose them via a bind-mount. I would like to migrate these files to a Docker volume, but their size is an issue.

These files compress well, down to 15 GB. Is it possible to take advantage of that compression in the Docker volume, to avoid eagerly decompressing the full 80 GB to the host? For example, can a Docker volume use SquashFS or similar for on-demand decompression?

Things I've tried:

- Using the btrfs storage driver, but this requires that the host be configured with a dedicated block device.
- Using `fuse-zip` and mounting inside the container, but this is very hacky and requires extending additional SYS_ADMIN capabilities to the container.

In case it's relevant, the files are accessed linearly, not random-access. Thank you for any help!

Comment: What exactly is the basic problem you want to solve/avoid here? Copying the data to the hosts? Decompressing them on the host? Or not to copy the data into each container? If it is the later, what is the problem with bind-mounting? It actually sounds like a viable solution^^

Comment: I hope to avoid eagerly decompressing the files onto the host. The issue with bind-mounting is the need to copy the data to the hosts before running the app - it would be preferable to just use docker-compose to manage the data, like any other image.